# a python script to retrieve a file from a remote VPN

Tags: python, download, vpn

I need to write a python script that logs into a remote VPN and then copies files from a certain directory to a directory on the local server.  What would be the best method to use for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have root access the easiest solution would be to:

- Execute the command to setup the VPN connection
- Execute the command to mount the remote directory
- Use [`shutil.copyfile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) to perform the copying. The module also has a function for recursive copying in case you need that.

If you don't you'll probably have a very hard time since you'd need to implement the protocol used by the VPN and do all the low-level network stuff the OS usually does in your script